# jQuery Set unique ID value increment from 1 instead of 0

Tags: jquery, dynamic, each, counter, increment

anybody feel like sharing their wisdom? I'm using the .each function to dynamically load some images. I used the following code to set the unique id to increment out as 'A0, A1, A2 and so on'... I want the first image to get the id 'A1' but at the moment it sets to 'A0'. Is there a simple way to set the id to increment from 1 up?

("id": "A" + i,)

```
$(window).load(function(){
td = $('#A .AS');
td.each(function (i) {
    var img = $("<img ondragstart='dragStart(event)'  onclick='sold(this.id)' onmouseover='over(this.id)' onmouseout='out(this.id)'/>");
    img.attr({
        "id": "A" + i,
            "src": "images/available.gif",
            "alt": "available" + i,
            "style": "border:none",
            "title": "available",
            "draggable": "true",

});
$(this).append(img);
});
});
```

Comment: ("id": "A" + (i+1)) will do the job , right ?

Comment: Job Done alright. Too sleepy to think of the brackets there. Thanks you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the **each** function is providing you with the index the simplest way would be adding 1 to the index value. Which will then start id from 1 instead of 0.

```
$(window).load(function(){
td = $('#A .AS');
td.each(function (i) {
    var img = $("<img ondragstart='dragStart(event)'  onclick='sold(this.id)' onmouseover='over(this.id)' onmouseout='out(this.id)'/>");
    img.attr({
        "id": "A" + (i+1),
            "src": "images/available.gif",
            "alt": "available" + i,
            "style": "border:none",
            "title": "available",
            "draggable": "true",

});
$(this).append(img);
});
});
```